# Grouping custom metaboxes in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I am using the following code to add custom meta boxes to the admin of my custom post types.

```
 <?php 
$prefix = '_myType_'; 
global $meta_boxes;

$meta_boxes = array();

$meta_boxes[] = array(

    'id' => 'myType',
        'title' => 'myType Data',
         'pages' => array( 'myType' ),
         'context' => 'normal',
         'priority' => 'high',
         'fields' => array(



        array(
            'name' => 'Starts',
            'id'   => "{$prefix}starts",
            'type' => 'date',

            'js_options' => array(
                'appendText'      => '(yyyy-mm-dd)',
                'dateFormat'      => 'yy-mm-dd',
                'changeMonth'     => true,
                'changeYear'      => true,
                'showButtonPanel' => true,
            ),
        ),

        array(
            'name' => 'Ends',
            'id'   => "{$prefix}ends",
            'type' => 'date',

            'js_options' => array(
                'appendText'      => '(yyyy-mm-dd)',
                'dateFormat'      => 'yy-mm-dd',
                'changeMonth'     => true,
                'changeYear'      => true,
                'showButtonPanel' => true,
            ),
        ),
    )
);


function YOUR_PREFIX_register_meta_boxes()
{
    if ( !class_exists( 'RW_Meta_Box' ) )
        return;

    global $meta_boxes;
    foreach ( $meta_boxes as $meta_box )
    {
        new RW_Meta_Box( $meta_box );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'YOUR_PREFIX_register_meta_boxes' );
```

I have quite a few fields and I need a way to group the items together with something like a hr tag.
And for some reason i thought this would work

```
       array(
            'id' => 'box_1_hr',
            'name' => 'box_1_hr',
            'type' => 'hr',
            'options' => array(
                'width' => '100%',
                'color' => '#DFDFDF'
            )
        ),
```

But it didnt! 
Doesnt anyone have any ideas if this can be done?
Thanks

Comment: The `<hr>` tag is not able to group element. So why did you thought in the first place that this could work?

Comment: `HR` stands for *horizontal rule* in this case, meaning a line across the page.

Comment: Hi Hakre.
I thought i could fake group the element... I wanted to put a horizontal rule there to break the fields up into distinct sections rather than 'really' grouping them. The reason i tried to do that is because i thought i had seen it somewhere once before.

Comment: I think you want `fieldset`s with `legend`s and `label`s are the display control elements you're wanting for those checkboxes. See [the standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/elements.html) for more information.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your suggestions but its not the html fields that i need it is something specific to wordpress. the array above is the right format but i just dont know why it wont display in my form as intended... thanks